# Qt5 QLabel + QPixmap. Memory leak?

Tags: windows, qt, memory

I'm writing an application that prints out images.
Briefly, i have a QListWidget with file names and i have a QLabel for printing out.

Here is the initialization (if it's important):

```cpp
connect(ui->filesList, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this,
        SLOT(onFilesListItemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));

ui->contents->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

And here is the code:

```cpp
void MainWindow::onFilesListItemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item) {
    ui->contents->clear();
    QString filename = item->text();

    if (filename.split('.')[1]  == "png") {
        QPixmap pixmap(skinfolderpath + "/" + filename);

        if ((pixmap.height() > ui->contents->height()) || (pixmap.width() > ui->contents->width())) {
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(ui->contents->width(), ui->contents->height(),
                                   Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        }

        ui->contents->setPixmap(pixmap);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the memory adds up without being released. For example, if i click on a picture, the memory will get allocated. Then i click on another one, and memory adds up without freeing the space from the previous picture. That results in a huge memory usage in just a few mins of using the application, and that's definitely what i don't want to have.
So, is there a way to fix it? It obviously comes from a "floating" QPixmap somewhere but i don't know how to delete it.

For the implementation, i use `pixmap.scaled` instead of just setting `ui->contents->setScaledContents(true)` because in my case it will maintain the aspect ratio, but in case of `scaledContents` it wouldn't.
Also, i'm awared that `ui->contents->clear()` is useless here since re-setting the pixmap using `ui->contents->setPixmap` clears everything, but still, i was trying to find something that i'm missing.

Comment: The problem is elsewhere in your code. It almost looks as if you were creating and leaking `QLabel`s. Likely `ui->contents` is leaked - you'd need to show us a minimum example that reproduces this. I also don't understand what has printing got to do with anything, and why you'd use a `QLabel` to print. Did you mean to say that you use `QLabel` to **display** the image?

Comment: @KubaOber well, aside from that code, there's nothing more. QListWidget (created statically in the .ui) that has a itemClicked signal bound to that slot function above. And a QLabel (created statically in the .ui as well). There is no more code regarding the issue and the process of loading-displaying the image in general. And yeah sorry i meant displaying not printing.

Comment: What Qt version is that? What is the compiler you use? If you compiled Qt itself, I'll also need to see the parameters you passed to configure (they'll be in a dot file in the root of the build directory). I'll try and reproduce this. It *would help* if you put everything into one file and didn't use .ui but build up the ui manually. That way it'd be a single, self contained example.

Comment: @KubaOber i use Qt 5.4.1 32 bit (bundled with Qt Creator 3.3.2) and as a compiler i use MinGW 4.9.1 32 bit. If you really want to have a working example, [here](https://github.com/ohyou/osu-skin-viewer) is the git repository with the code. The part i'm talking about is in `src/mainwindow.cpp` function starts at line 98. The code is a big mess now and to be refactored after i fix the issue.

Comment: @KubaOber to make that app work all you need is the following file structure: `rootdir/Skins/folders/images` where rootdir is where you point at with using the menu `Tools -> change osu! folder`. `Folders` are just folders and `images` are png only

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Qt::SmoothTransformation, I had the same issue, Qt::FastTransformation solved the memory leak.