# Qt6 QLabel / QPixmap excessive memory usage

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, pyqt, qt6, pyqt6

I have an application where I need to put background images on many QLabels using QPixmap. This uses what to me seems to be an excessive amount of memory, which made me suspect that it's due to a memory leak. From the comments I understand that an image in memory may occupy a lot more space than on file but I was surprised that the difference would be so big.

I'm using PyQt6 on MacOS Ventura.

Here is a simple piece code to reproduce. The image file size is 1 MB and this simple application uses more than 4 GB of RAM.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QLabel,QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QMainWindow()

for i in range(20):

    label = QLabel(w)

    # The file size of the image is 1 MB
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap('image.png'))

w.show()

app.exec()
```

The only related issue I have found is this but I could not get anything useful from it:

[Qt5 QLabel + QPixmap. Memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276146/qt5-qlabel-qpixmap-memory-leak)

The background in my application is that I am making plots with Matplotlib that I want to keep in many different windows / tabs. I have experienced problems with excessive memory usage when using many Matplotlib figures and hence I am looking at using one single figure to produce each plot as an image to be put on a separate QLabel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why you think there is a memory leak -- apparent excess memory usage is not necessarily a leak.  Also, what do you mean by `"The image size is 1 MB"`: is that the size of the PNG file on disk?  If so, note that the size on disk needn't bear any resemblance to the uncompressed size in memory.

Comment: Exactly what G.M. says. Images are stored in memory as raw byte collections: the file size is completely irrelevant, as PNG uses compression, so what actually matters is the image *pixel* size and depth: an image roughly occupies `(width×height×depth)/8` in memory. That said, Qt should be able to cache the same image to some extent, so what you describe should *not* happen. Can you please specify the details about that image? Also, did you try the same code with PyQt5?

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, seems I may have misunderstood then what the expected expected image size in memory would be. In my application each image will be different, it was just in this example to reproduce that I used the same image. If it indeed is expected to have 4 GB of RAM usage for displaying 20 images that are 1 MB on file then I can close this question. I have not tried the same code in PyQt5

Comment: @Bearify The real question is: does the *exact* code above reproduce the issue? If not, and that only happens with *different* images, then you did *not* provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, the code above uses more than 4 GB of RAM. But what I am really interested in is the case with different images, as that will be the case in my application.

Comment: @Bearify Be aware that caching a plot as image is not automatically a performance improvement, especially memory-wise and if you're trying to cache the image at high resolution; imagine a plot that simply draws a circle, and you "cache" it by storing the image at 4000x4000: it *could* virtually occupy up to 60mb of ram (it normally won't, as Qt is smart), while the plot itself would probably require less than 10-20kB; the image would most certainly load faster (since its raster contents are already in memory) but the plot would probably require more time due to its complex nature.

Comment: @Bearify That said, the issue you're describing might be possible due to very high *dimensions* of the image (not its file size), which you never provided. I'm under the impression that if the image exceeds the default memory allocation, it cannot be cached, causing excessive memory usage.

Comment: The dimensions are 2880 x 3840 pixels. I may re-consider the option of plotting. As mentioned I have experienced memory leaks with Matplotlib figures that I have not been able to resolve despite the available tips online about closing / clearing figures etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not related to the image *file size*, but its contents: images, as much as video or audio, can use compression (lossy or not), but their *memory* usage will be the same.

Roughly speaking, an image normally occupy as much memory as its raw image data; the simple formula is:

```
memorySizeInBytes = (image.width * image.height * image.depth) / 8
```

Luckily, Qt is quite smart, and its image objects (QImage and QPixmap) are optimized to store data that *actually* paint contents.

Also, Qt uses an internal cache for pixmaps (see [QPixmapCache](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmapcache.html)) that sets its amount only based on the possible *cost* of the image, using a formula similar to the above. While not extremely optimal, it's understandable: even if the *stored* memory size of the image is potentially much less than its actual usage, that pixmap might be modified and increase its memory consumption.

The default size for the above cache is normally set to 10240kB, meaning that any image that has an area and depth that exceeds the current cache size more than the 10240kB limit will **not** be cached.

The above raises another important issue: while caching the "image" of an object might seem a good performance "workaround", it creates a serious problem considering what written above: each new image that will exceed the current used pixmap cache size will be ignored, and each *new* instance of that image will be considered as a new, unique image data object.
For a standard QPixmap, whenever its area and bit depth exceeds the `10240kB` limit, it will *not* be cached, and cannot be "reloaded" even if it has already been previously loaded. While annoying, this behavior is a safety measure for smaller (and usually more commonly used/drawn) pixmaps, including icons, which are probably drawn more frequently.

Be aware that creating pixmaps as cache of complex objects does not automatically make it an optimization: while raster data is faster to read (as long as the data has been already read), it can easily decrease performance, especially if compared to dynamic painting that actually requires far more smaller memory allocation.

So, you must try to find out if the rendered image *real* size and depth goes beyond the default limit, and eventually consider possible alternatives.

There are some possibilities, for instance:

- just render the pixmap in the paint event handler (usually, `paintEvent()` of the widget); while not as optimal as a basic QPixmap shown on a QLabel, it will certainly improve memory management;
- use [QPicture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpicture.html) as a form of cache, but drawing the result of the widget directly on it (and not as a rasterized render); this is how pyqtgraph normally draws its items, which may not be extremely optimal for speed performance, but rather good for memory management;

Finally, be aware that the default cache limit of the global QPixmapCache can be changed, and you can also *clear* cached pixmaps whenever you're sure that you won't use them anymore. So, you can use [`setCacheLimit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmapcache.html#setCacheLimit) to a reasonable kB size (possibly based on system information), store each pixmap using [`insert()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmapcache.html#insert-1) while storing its key and eventually [`remove()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmapcache.html#remove-1) its key whenever the figure is going to be destroyed.